# Почему в массив не добавляются элементы?

Tags: ios, swift

Имеется код :

```
 func loadShots(shotsUrl: String, completion: (([Shot]) -> Void)!) {
        let urlString = "https://api.dribbble.com/v1/shots?access_token=" + accessToken
        let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
        let shotUrl = NSURL(string: urlString) 
        let task = session.dataTaskWithURL(shotUrl!) {
            (data, response, error) -> Void in
            if error != nil {
                print(error?.localizedDescription)
            } else {
                var shots = [Shot]()
                var error : NSError?
                var shotsData =   try? NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: .MutableContainers ) as! NSArray
                for shot in shotsData! {
                    let shot = Shot(data: shot as! NSDictionary)
                    shots.append(shot)
                }
            let prioriry = DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(prioriry, 0)) {
                    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                        completion(shots)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        task.resume()
    }
```

Почему shots после билда показывает 0 элементов? что я сделал неправильно?

Comment: а вы уверены, что вам с сервера что то пришло? и где именно вы пытаетесь вывести содержание массива (он у вас объявлен внутри блока, так что долго не живет). И переименуйте `shot` на всякий случай, у вас там их два.

Comment: и чтоб два раза не вставать, у вас `Shot(data:)` точно принимает Dictionary? мне что то кажется, что NSData там имела бы больше смысла

Comment: с сервера приходят данные, получаю 40000 байт(если навести на shotsData, либо прописать в консоле вывода "po shotsData", а когда навожу на Shot, либо po Shot пишет 0 values. хотя по идее он должен быть заполнен.

Comment: как я уже сказал - переименуйте один из shot, и проверьте что ваш инит знает, что делать с Dictionary

Comment: init(data: NSDictionary) {
        self.id = data["id"] as! Int
        
        let shots = data["image"] as! NSDictionary
        
        self.imageUrl = getStringFromJSON(shots, key: "normal")
    }

Comment: если переименовать, ошибки выдает

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема была в неверно описанном `init`, класса `Shot`